# Everytime i run "jupyter notebook", why I always got this on mac os?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, jupyter-notebook

Everytime i ran "jupyter notebook" on my mac os, why always got this error?

case:

1. i have python2.x and i installed python3.7 (so, i have two commands here)
2. i installed jupyter with pip
3. when i put jupyter notebook command, i always got these error

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
  sys.exit(main())
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
  return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
  app.start()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1697, in start
  browser = webbrowser.get(self.browser or None)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/webbrowser.py", line 42, in get
  register_standard_browsers()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/webbrowser.py", line 531, in register_standard_browsers
  raw_result = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 376, in check_output
  **kwargs).stdout
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 453, in run
  with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
  restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1499, in _execute_child
  raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'xdg-settings'
```

Comment: How did you install Python 3.7 and Jupyter? `xdg-settings` is a Common Desktop component, i.e. not available on OSX.

Comment: @tripleee i installed it by download it from python website, so wht should i do? did i do a mistakes?

Comment: For a start, please [edit] your question to explain in more detail what you did. Is Jupyter really distributed on Python.org now?

Comment: @tripleee sorry, i mean i installed python3.7 from python website, and i install jupyter notebook with pip

Comment: Looks like this is an open issue for `jupyter` combined with Python 3.7, see [issue #3746](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3746). The workaround proposed there is to pass the `--no-browser` option and then manually navigate to the notebook in browser.

Comment: @hoefling thanks it solved with `jupyter notebook --no-browser` command, but i don't know why it always . print those error everytime i run `jupyter notebook` without `--no-brower` flag (if i were not wrong to spell it correctly)

Comment: Because this is probably a bug in `jupyter` that will be fixed by the devs sooner or later, maybe already in the next version.

Comment: @hoefling's comment should be the answer

Answer (score 2):

From [warp-x](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3746#issuecomment-405007446): If you don't mind opening your browser manually, you can pass `--no-browser` when starting the notebook: `$ jupyter notebook --no-browser`.
You can then open your browser, navigate to the notebook in a browser (normally `localhost:8888`) manually and do you your work.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same `NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20]`. In your case, the file it is pointing to is `'xdg-settings'`.

It seems that the file `'xdg-settings'` might be a shortcut and the actual file can't be found. What you can do is simply **delete that file (ONLY if it is a shortcut)**. Then restart jupyter notebook and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this error, here's how you solve it ([credit to @rrios-eq on Github](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3746#issuecomment-444957821)):

> It's a if/else logic bug in `webbrowser.py`; a simple fix is to edit
> `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/webbrowser.py`
> (or wherever Jupyter is pointing you to) and then look for
> `xdg-settings` in the code.
>
> Several lines above (15 in my case), you will have if `sys.platform[:3] == "win":` if you change it to `elif sys.platform[:3] == "win":` then the Darwin/Windows/Linux will work properly. I'm running python3.7 from
> Homebrew using macOS 10.14.2.

Comment: This is the answer. The key is to find xdg-settings first, as the sys.platform if statement appears more than once in other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Find the file `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/webbrowser.py` and then the function `register_standard_browsers` and then look for `if sys.platform[:3] == "win":` and change it by `elif sys.platform[:3] == "win":` and save the file, it should work.